# How to call your own method using "this" on a DOM node

Tags: javascript

I would like to make something like this:

```js
function alrtHtml() {
  alert(this.innerHTML)
}

function myFunc(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).alrtHtml()
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 id="h1">Hello world!</h1>
  <input type="button" value="click" onclick="myFunc('h1')" >
</body>
</html>
```

The result should be an alert with the text "Hello world!" inside the `h1` tag.

It is my goal to be able to do this without explicitly passing the element as an argument to `alertHtml`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You generally don't want to extend native prototypes, and one way to create chainable methods without doing that, is to create your own method to get the elements, and then create another chainable method to alert the `innerHTML`, like most libraries do.

Probably the simplest example would be something like this

```js
function getElement(selector) {
  if (!(this instanceof getElement)) return new getElement(selector);
  this.element = document.querySelector(selector);
  return this;
}

getElement.prototype.alertHtml = function() {
  alert(this.element.innerHTML);
  return this;
}

function myFunc(id) {
  getElement(id).alertHtml();
}

myFunc('#test');
```

```html
<div id="test">TEST</div>
```

This way you're only extending your own objects, not native objects, and you can create any kind of chainable method to add to that.

Comment: amazing code but can you explain me the first line of function getElement()?

Comment: @SkyCrafter - It's a trick, if the function isn't called with `new` it's not an instance of itself, so we call it again with `new` to create an instance, and the next time the condition is skipped. It's a common way to create instances without having to do `new getElement` every time, jQuery and several other libraries do the same thing internally.

Comment: @SkyCrafter - we all make typos like that, and they can be really hard to spot sometimes, often it's harder to spot the obvious typos the longer you've been looking at the code, trying to spot them.

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking to do is add your function to the [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) of whatever type `document.getElementById(id)` returns.

In this case it's returning an `Element`, so in order to add your function to its prototype you would write the following code.

```
Element.prototype.alrtHtml = function() {
  alert(this.innerHTML)
}
```

Comment: Dominic you had the right idea, but try to write valid JS next time :p

Comment: Yea I noticed your edits. Thank you very much for making the answer much clearer! I'm still new to Stack Overflow and how to make good answers so I really appreciate your help!

Comment: That's a very bad practice and certainly not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

As another alternative, you could also pass the element right to `alertHTML`:

```js
function alertHTML(el) {
  alert(el.innerHTML)
}

function myFunc(id) {
  var elArg = document.getElementById(id)
  alertHTML(elArg)
  
  // You could also write it like this:
  /*
  alertHTML(document.getElementById('h1'))
  */
}
```

```html
<h1 id='h1'>Hello, world</h1>
<button onclick="myFunc('h1')">Button</button>
```

There's a plethora of reasons to do that, but the gist of it is to avoid having issues if somebody else creates a `alertHTML` method on the `Element` prototype.

EDIT: If you *really* want to use `this`, you might also like to learn about binding functions - [funfunfunction made a good video on this here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GhbhD1HR5vk). Here's how that would work:

```js
function alertHTML() {
  alert(this.innerHTML)
}

function myFunc(id) {
  var el = document.getElementById(id)
  alertHTML.apply(el)
}
```

```html
<h1 id='h1'>Hello, world</h1>
<button onclick="myFunc('h1')">Button</button>
```

[`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) runs whatever its function is with `this` as the first argument you pass to `apply`. (The rest of the arguments you pass to `apply` are passed directly to the function.)